# Openpyxl сохраняет только integer

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

Пример кода с оффициального сайта openpyxl.
В таблицу должны вывести цифры и слова. Если цифру взять в скобки она считается типом string и не выводится.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook


wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
treeData = [["Type", "Leaf Color", "Height"], ["Maple", "Red", "549"], ["Oak", "Green", 783], ["Pine", "Green", 1204]]
for row in treeData:
    ws.append(row)

wb.save("TreeData.xlsx")
```

[image: Вывод таблицы]

Comment: Виндоус 10, питон 3.11 ваша ошибка не воспроизводиться.